Fetching data from graph using GraphServiceClient
I am trying to fetch invitation events from the calendar using GraphServiceClient in C#:
public async Task<int> GetInvitationEventsCount(string _start, string _end)
        {
             GraphServiceClient client = await GetClient();

            //we are not using this isOrganizerFilter condition because if i am the organizer the responseStatus/response value will be organizer
            string filter = "isOrganizer eq false and ((responseStatus/response eq 'none') or (responseStatus/response eq 'notResponded') or (responseStatus/response eq 'tentativelyAccepted'))";
            var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
            {
                new QueryOption("startDateTime", _start),
                new QueryOption("endDateTime", _end),
                new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
                new QueryOption("$top", "0")
            };

            List<Event> events = new List<Event>();
            int _eventsCount=0;
           
            try
            {
                var _events = await client.Me.Calendar.CalendarView
               .Request(queryOptions)
               .Filter(filter)
               .WithCustomUserAssertion(userAssertion)
               .GetAsync();
                _eventsCount = Convert.ToInt32(_events.AdditionalData["@odata.count"].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
            return _eventsCount;
        }

I get an internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
I have tried to make two different filters the first isOrganizer eq false and the second for this
string filter = "isOrganizer eq false and ((responseStatus/response eq 'none') or (responseStatus/response eq 'notResponded') or (responseStatus/response eq 'tentativelyAccepted'))
but I get this error :Query option '$filter' was specified more than once, but it must be specified at most once.
